Как выполнить запрос channels.editAdmin, используя TdLib .NET C#?
Есть .NET C# проект. К нему подключен nuget-пакет TdLib.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне выполнить запрос: https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.editAdmin используя данную библиотеку?
Честно говоря вообще не понимаю, как пользоваться данной документацией, примеров для .NET C# не нашёл.
Если я правильно понимаю существует несколько вариантов выполнения запросов:
//Using strongly typed APIs example
using TdLib;

var client = new TdClient();
TdApi.Ok ok = await client.ExecuteAsync(new TdApi.SetAuthenticationPhoneNumber
{
    PhoneNumber = phoneNumber
});

и
//Using json client
using TdLib;

var json = ""; // json data
double timeout = 1.0; // 1 second

using (var jsonClient = new TdJsonClient())
{
    jsonClient.Send(json); // send request
    var result = jsonClient.Receive(timeout); // receive response
}

Собственно вопрос: как выполнить запрос channels.editAdmin, используя первый или второй вариант?
UPD:
Нашёл пример кода вызова данного метода в JS:
// make the bot an admin of the channel
        const makeAdmin: Api.TypeUpdates = await client.invoke(
          new Api.channels.EditAdmin({
            channel: new Api.InputChannel({
              channelId: channelId as bigInt.BigInteger,
              accessHash: accessHash as bigInt.BigInteger,
            }),
            userId: '@BotNameHere',
            adminRights: new Api.ChatAdminRights({
              changeInfo: true,
              postMessages: true,
              editMessages: true,
              deleteMessages: true,
              banUsers: true,
              inviteUsers: true,
              pinMessages: true,
              addAdmins: true,
              anonymous: false,
              manageCall: true,
              other: false,
            }),
            rank: 'Administrator',
          })
        );
        if (makeAdmin instanceof Api.Updates) {
          logger.info('Bot is now an admin of the channel');
        }
      }``

`
Но как его адаптировать под мою ситуацию всё равно непонятно.
